# Missing Menu In Header

Tags: html, wordpress

setting up a basic website. I know basic HTML & CSS, but it's only enough to at least play around.

I was using WordPress editor to change some of the code, now the menu for my header has disappeared (contains home, blog, contact).

Website: http://onwardsdigital.com.au/

I can see it's still their in the source code so not sure why I can't see it and it's visible on mobile version.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Your css has this entry:

```
#main-nav-mobile {
display:none;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
```

That is being used by the DIV with the class main-nav-mobile.  If you get rid of the display:none, it will show up.  Did you come up with that entry, or is it Wordpress?  If Wordpress, you might want to ask the people who did the template why they have that class set to not display.

Comment: hey doug, thanks for your reply. that was wordpress, but i'm fine with the dropdown menu on the mobile version. it's moreso that i can't see a menu on the desktop/tablet version